# gitlab: Is there a way to http access an artifact during a job, rather than after?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to run a pipeline with two stages. The first stage creates a zip file and the second stage executes a http curl POST for that file. If the curl succeeds, the pipeline is completed.

The problem is that gitlab only exposes the zip file AFTER the pipeline has completed - which means the zip file from the previous pipeline gets sent instead.

I've tried using artifacts and dependencies, but it seems the http url is only exposed for completed pipelines. I tried using the url of the specific job that executed the build stage, but it didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to access an artifact by URL, before pipeline completion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was unable to find a way to access the artifact remotely before the pipeline had completed. sad face.

i have a workaround though - i moved the deploy stage to a separate pipeline. so the first pipeline just executes the build (generating the artifacts) and then triggers the second pipeline. the second pipeline is then able to access the artifacts of the first pipeline and it just executes a deploy stage. happy face.